# Nullifying an angle in a Rotation Matrix

Tags: math, matrix, rotational-matrices

Say I have a Rotation Matrix, which is used to rotate a 3D model.
Is it possible to set the yaw of the rotation matrix to zero before applying it to the model?

Regards, Adam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RotMatrix**=***R***(yaw)***R**(pitch)***R**(roll)

to eliminate yaw factor, we can left-multiply this matrix on negative yaw matrix

**RotMatrixNew**=***R**(-yaw)**R(yaw)***R**(pitch)***R**(roll) = ***I******R**(pitch)***R**(roll) = **R**(pitch)***R**(roll)

If yaw angle isn't known before, then it could be calculated as

yaw = ArcTan2(RotMatrix[2][1], RotMatrix[1][1])